# What happens with SharePoint Online Remote Event Receivers if the receiver is down?

Tags: sharepoint-online

[The documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj220048.aspx) for SharePoint Online Remote Event Receivers is not clear on the durability of events. If a provider hosted add-in registers a RER and then subsequently goes down (say, for maintenance), what happens to events that occur while the receiver is unavailable? Are they queued and retried by SharePoint Online until the add-in comes back online, or are they lost? If they are queued, for how long?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately I can only tell you something about my experience with it - I don't have anything official for this...

As far as I know the events won't be queued nor are they retried after the add-in comes back online.

The events are just pointing to nowhere.

As I said, this is not an official statement or something - just my experience.
Any information input is welcome.

Comment: After >12 months I don't think I'm going to get a more official statement - so you get the green tick!

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately it's difficult sometimes to get official statements :(